# Update two table using store procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to update one column in table family and two column's in parent table. 
I know how to do it in sql. I tried it by seeing some examples, and it worked if i tried to update it in sql directly but i can't update using store procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_EditProfile(
IN inputfamilyName VARCHAR(45),
inputuserName VARCHAR(45), 
inputfamilyID INT(20),
inputparentID INT(20)
)
BEGIN
update family, parent SET family.familyName= inputfamilyName, parent.userName=inputuserName WHERE family.FamilyID=inputfamilyID AND parent.ParentID=inputfamilyID;
END
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: @Adam no error. It has to update 1 row, its not doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry @AdamSilenko.. Its working now :) Thanks

Comment: just updated WHERE parent.ParentID=inputparentID; in your code. worked perfectly. @AdamSilenko

Comment: but in your sql is the same condition...

Comment: @AdamSilenko I'm sorry... Than its my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) .

You can do this (to test call):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_EditProfile(
IN inputfamilyName VARCHAR(45),
inputuserName VARCHAR(45), 
inputfamilyID INT(20),
inputparentID INT(20)
)
BEGIN
  UPDATE family 
  SET familyName= inputfamilyName
  WHERE family.FamilyID=inputfamilyID;

  UPDATE parent 
  SET userName=inputuserName 
  WHERE parent.ParentID=inputfamilyID;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it is not updating in the database. It has to update 1 row. but it doesn't do that.

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.1112 seconds.)